# WP + WooCommerce custom search form weird behavior

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I added a custom woocommerce products search form, using the code below.

```html
<form action="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>" method="get" role="search">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="" required="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" >
    <button class="searchfixed-submit" type="submit">
      *(some svg image)*
    </button>
</form>
```

It actually works like a fine: search results show only products, the page URL is `?/s=term&post_type=product` and the page is rendered with the `/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`. Therefore, it uses the same layout as the shop pages to display the products.

However, this only works for logged in users. If I run a search from incognito mode Chrome or Edge, or even from my phone, this reverts to the default page results : search results show everything (posts, products, pages, ...), the page URL is `?/s=term` and the page is rendered with the `/generatepress/search.php`. Therefore, I loose my customizations.

Moreover, when entering directly the URL containg the desired post_type, this redirects to the default URL automatically when the user is logged off.

Is this a know issue, that can be worked around? Or am I missing some stuff ?

**EDIT: I did miss some stuff: Yoast**

For any user out here in the same situation, this behavior was due to some of Yoast configuration. If you enable the URL cleaning feature, you have to make sure you add the `post_type` url param to the whitelist.

Consider closed.